# Array of structures

Tags: solidity, struct, ethereumj

How to store the returned array of structs from a contract to some other contract?
Like for eg. I have a doctor contract that has the function as :

```
function getRegisteredDoctors() public view returns(DoctorDetails [] memory) {
    DoctorDetails[] memory doctorArray = new DoctorDetails[](doctorAddress.length);
    
    for(uint i = 0; i < doctorAddress.length; i++) {
      doctorArray[i] = doctors[doctorAddress[i]];
    }
    
    return doctorArray;
  }
```

DoctorDetails is a structure for me consisting of fields such as `address id,string name,string clinicName,string department,string password`.

Now I have another contract Clinic.sol that needs to access this array of structure. One function that I was trying is as:

```
function doctorNaturalJoinPatient() public view returns(doctorNaturalJoinPatientResult[] memory){
        Doctor doctorContract = Doctor(doctorContractAddress);
        Patient patientContract = Patient(patientContractAddress);

        doctorDetails[] memory dDetails = doctorContract.getRegisteredDoctors();
    }
```

Ignore the patient.sol for now. Again here doctorDetails is a struct in Clinic.sol having fields same as that of doctor.sol as described above. But I'm getting a warning `Type struct Doctor.DoctorDetails[] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct Clinic.doctorDetails[] memory.`

How to hanlde this case of accessing an array of struct from one contract to another contract?

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep same struct in both contracts. You can also make library and keep struct in it and you can use the same library in the both contracts.There will be function in client.sol that accepts that struct in form of tuple. You can apply external call to client.sol contract from getRegisteredDoctors() function. I hope this solves your problem.